# how to combine two selectors?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

in my example http://jsfiddle.net/radek/HnXC4/2/ I defined jQuery handler for click

- on **button**
- that have a class **run**

via `$(":button, .run").click(function(){`

how come the `this button should NOT work` button's clicked is fired too? It doesn't have class "run".

Comment: Your selector matches any `:button` elements, or any elements with a `.run` class. So it's not necessary for an element to fulfill both criteria, just either one.

Comment: I tried `$(":button .run").click(function(){` before posting my question. And it didn't work. The space is very important.

Comment: Be careful with a plain class selection $('.something') - it's a very slow, expensive operation in older, slower browsers or big documents. It scans every single element in the document!

Comment: It's not the space that's important. It's the lack of it that is. That selector selects elements with `.run` class **inside** `:button` elements. It's different from what you're asking for.

Comment: @BoltClock: uff, thank you for pointing this out. I need a guide to selectors. Could you recommend one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
$(":button.run").click(function(){
```

`$(":button, .run")` will match any elements that are either buttons or have a CSS class of `run`.

Comment: Longer answer: the comma means **or**, so anything that is *either* a **button** or has class **run** will fire.  To **and** them, you have to concatenate the strings, as in @Andrew's example.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the comma in between:

```
$(":button.run").click(function(){};
```

Answer (score 4):

What you want is:

```
$(":button.run").click(function(){});
```

This means "all buttons that ALSO have the class 'run'".  When you include a comma in the selectors, it means "all elements that are buttons, *as well as* all elements that have class 'run'", as you had here:

```
$(":button, .run").click(function(){});
```

For completeness, if you have a space in the selector without the comma, such as:

```
$(":button .run").click(function(){});
```

That means all elements with class 'run' that are descendents of buttons.  Not sure buttons can have descendents, but you get the idea.

Comment: Well, `<button>` elements can have descendants, but not `<input type="button">` because the latter is an empty element.